# Difference between BTSP and TSP

Tags: algorithms, traveling-salesman

I am wondering what is the difference between Bottleneck Travelling Salesman Problem and normal Travelling Salesman Problem?

Thank you

Comment: Is there something wrong with the explanation in wikipedia?

Comment: I just don't get it well. That is why I asked. It says "discrete or combinatorial optimization".

Comment: I am actually trying to find a good heuristic algorithm for solving 2d plain(coordinate system) traveling salesman problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTSP asks to find a Hamiltonian cycle in a weighted graph, which minimizes the weight of its most weighty edge.

TSP asks to find a Hamiltonian cycle in a weighted graph, which minimizes the sum of weights of its edges.